# Making thematic layer 50% translucent in MapBasic?

Tags: layers, mapbasic, transparency-opacity, thematic-map

I'm trying to make this enhancement to an old program written by another author.
I was able to make the layer translucent prior to Shade Window command, but its not working.
Here is the code:

```
Add Map Window nMapId Auto Layer TRADE_AREAS
Set Map Window nMapId Zoom Entire Layer TRADE_AREAS
Set Map Window nMapId Layer TRADE_AREAS
Set Map Window nMapId Layer TRADE_AREAS Alpha 127
    Label
        Position Center 
        Font (Verdana, 0, 5, BLACK)
        With Zip_code
        Auto On Overlap Off

objBuffer = Buffer(objStore, 100, fRadius, "mi")
Insert Into MKT_BUFFER (obj) Values (objBuffer)

sCmd = "Shade Window " & nMapId & " TRADE_AREAS With Trade_Area Values "
        + """Primary"" Pen (1,2,0) Brush (2,16711680,16777215), "  'RED, WHITE
        + """Secondary"" Pen (1,2,0) Brush (2,65280,16777215), "   'GREEN, WHITE
        + """Tertiary"" Pen (1,2,0) Brush (2,16776960,16777215) "    'YELLOW WHITE
Run Command sCmd
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the Thematic layer translucent as well once you have created it.

You can loop the layers in the map until you locate TRADE_AREAS. The thematic map will be the layer before: nLayer - 1, where nLayer is your loop variable.

```
Set Map Window nMapId Layer (nLayer - 1) Alpha 127
```